# Create empty catalina.out from cron job (based on just-deleted catalina.out)

Tags: bash, tomcat, cron

I have a bash script that successfully deletes catalina.out files for one or more tomcat log directories (we run multiple instances) once the file exceeds a certain size. I run this script nightly as a cron job. It essentially looks like this:

```
find /apache-tomcat-blah*/. -name catalina.out -size +1000M -delete
```

However, my problem is I need to automatically create a new empty one in its place as soon as the old one is deleted.

The challenge is I will not know ahead of time which catalina.out from which tomcat instance was deleted. Also, I do not want to assume I know all the tomcat instances corresponding to /apache-tomcat-blah*/. We change them from time to time.

I assume the find command knows what it just deleted (maybe I should not assume that) so that I could theoretically pipe that information as in:

```
$ echo "" > /apache-tomcat-justDeletedFromDir/logs/catalina.out
```

if I could figure out what to put in the **apache-tomcat-justDeletedFromDir** part of the string.

I would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Note that '>' is a redirection, not a pipe. Pipes refer to inter-process comms, not files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use something like:

```
for f in $(find /apache-tomcat-blah*/. -name catalina.out -size +1000M); do
   rm $f
   touch $f
done
```

so your `find` command is now executed in a subshell `$()`, and your bash script iterates through the output (the list of files) and removes each one (via `rm`) and creates a new one (via `touch`)

You would need to be careful with the above if your files have spaces in them (note).

Comment: Thanks @Brian Agnew , that has great promise. I will try that right away.